# How will i get the output xyz by destructuring in javaScript?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

How can I get `activities.activity1[1].song_list.song_2` from this object using destructuring?

```js
let activities = {
  activity1: [{
      name: "listen on spotify",
      song_list: {
        song_1: "abc",
        song_2: "bcd"
      },
      id: 1
    },
    {
      name: "listen music through bot",
      song_list: {
        song_1: "wxy",
        song_2: "xyz"
      },
      id: 2
    }
  ]
};
```

Comment: Why would you use destructuring?

Comment: `const { activity1: { 1: { song_list: { song_2 } } } } = activities`

Comment: Why not simply use `activities.activity1[1].song_list.song_2` which would be much more readable than any destructuring assignment?

Comment: If either of the answers below solved your issue, then you should mark the one that best helped you as correct. This would help guide others with the same issue in the future.

Answer (score 1):

To do this without treating the array as an object:

```js
const activities = {"activity1":[{"name":"listen on spotify","song_list":{"song_1":"abc","song_2":"bcd"},"id":1},{"name":"listen music through bot","song_list":{"song_1":"wxy","song_2":"xyz"},"id":2}]}

const { activity1: [, { song_list: {song_2}}]} = activities;

console.log(song_2)
```

Answer (score 0):

As [Spectric](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14251221/spectric) pointed out in the comments, you can use this:

```js
let activities = {
  activity1: [{
      name: "listen on spotify",
      song_list: {
        song_1: "abc",
        song_2: "bcd"
      },
      id: 1
    },
    {
      name: "listen music through bot",
      song_list: {
        song_1: "wxy",
        song_2: "xyz"
      },
      id: 2
    }
  ]
};

const { activity1: {1: { song_list: {song_2}}}} = activities;
console.log(song_2)
```

This destructuring works because arrays are actually objects with integer keys, so `1` becomes the second value in the array.

This might be a cool trick or fun puzzle, but in the real world destructuring is not the best move here. [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) states the purpose of destructuring as,

> The destructuring assignment syntax is a JavaScript expression that makes it possible to unpack values from arrays, or properties from objects, into distinct variables.

You should only destructure stuff that you need to get multiple variables from, otherwise, it will make your code uglier.